# Passing object to another variable

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript

I'm trying to unit test the query function. When I debug with a breakpoint at the unit test below, I see that `this.datasets = Object` with the `dataset` info in my unit test. However, when I step into the query function, data is undefined. Why is it undefined and how do I set it to the `dataset` in my unit test?

QueryController.ts:

```
public query(query: QueryRequest): QueryResponse {
    Log.trace('QueryController::query( ' + JSON.stringify(query) + ' )');
    let data: any = this.datasets["courses"];

    // do stuff 
}
```

Unit test:

```
it("Valid query", function () {
    let query: QueryRequest = {
        // valid query code here
    };
    let dataset: Datasets = {
        "234": {
            "courses_dept": "math",
            "courses_id": "327",
            "courses_avg": 86.17,
            "courses_instructor": "spears, britney",
            "courses_title": "opera appreciation",
            "courses_pass": 23,
            "courses_fail": 10,
            "courses_audit": 10
        },
    };
    let controller = new QueryController(dataset);
    let ret = controller.query(query);

    //check stuff
});
```

**Edit:** I fixed the problem. query() was calling this.datasets["courses"]. I needed to add a "courses" key to my dataset in the unit test.

Comment: What is `QueryController`?

Comment: @Roque  `QueryController` is the class that the query function is in.

Comment: Alright (I guessed that). Did you code it yourself? It looks like this class is responsible for your issue. I don't see any problem with the core you are showing here. Are you sure the `datasets` property is properly assigned in the constructor? By the way, are you sure the member name is `datasets` and not `dataset`?

Comment: @Roque I wrote most of it but not the constructor. Does it look OK? `export default class QueryController {
    private datasets: Datasets = null;

    constructor(datasets: Datasets) {
        this.datasets = datasets;
    }`

Comment: Change `"234"` to `"courses"`. You are accessing non existing key...